# correct formation of if elif else statement in Python

Tags: python

Please find the below code block in python 2.7.

```
for i in range(len(p_routes)):
    if len(p_routes[i]) > 2 :
        if p_routes[i][2] == 'No Backup':   
            K = K + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i])):
                nbup.write(K + 1 , z , p_routes[i][z])

        elif p_routes[i][0][0] == 'E' :
            L = L + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i])):
                ex.write(L, z , (p_routes[i][z])

        elif p_routes[i][0][0] == 'G':
            M = M + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i]))
                gh.write(M ,z, p_routes[i][z])

    else len(p_routes[i]) < 2:
        pass
        print "\nFor some reason. "
```

Well, I am getting an syntax error saying `elif p_routes[i][0][0] == 'G':` . I couldn't figure out why this error is coming as I believe there is no syntax error in this line.

The `ex` and `gh` are two excel sheet variable created before this code block. And `p_routes` is a list of list of 2 degrees. The format is like `p_routes = [['prov1' , 'address1' , 'No Backup'] , ['prov2', 'address2', 'Back1', 'Back2' ]]`

You might have understood, that the inner list length is a variable size. Any advise would be much appreciated. Sorry for the silly question but I did a lot of searching and re-formatting my `if..else` block in number of ways. But every time I am getting this error.

By the way previously the syntax error was with `L = L + 1`. Funny! Then I changed the type of L by `L = int(L)`. Now, that error is gone.

Comment: You will be getting an error on the `else` statement as well, `else` doesn't have a condition, it's what is done if all other conditions are false. Besides, both `pass` *and* a `print` statement?

Comment: It is syntax error `ex.write(L, z , (p_routes[i][z])` should be this `ex.write(L, z , (p_routes[i][z]))` and there are many other errors

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for your quick and to the point answer. As you pointed out, yes this was the issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

**Notes:**

Never forget to close the `(` with `)`

Else will execute `if none of the above case condition was right` so you should not give any condition to else statement

Don't forget `:` in `if else for.....`

**Changes to your code:**

```
for i in range(len(p_routes)):
    if len(p_routes[i]) > 2 :
        if p_routes[i][2] == 'No Backup':   
            K = K + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i])):
                nbup.write(K + 1 , z , p_routes[i][z])

        elif p_routes[i][0][0] == 'E' :
            L = L + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i])):
                ex.write(L, z , (p_routes[i][z]))

        elif p_routes[i][0][0] == 'G':
            M = M + 1
            for z in range(len(p_routes[i])):
                gh.write(M ,z, p_routes[i][z])

    else :
        pass
        print "\nFor some reason. "
```

Answer (score 1):

First off as Vignesh pointed out, your error is actually on the previous line as you forgot to close your parenthesis **(** **)**

Second, the else clause for the if, elif, else structure does not require a check. 
Here is a video I made a while ago with how selection works in python [linked to relevant time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivoi5sCMGIQ&t=553)

(May not be relevant)
Also keep in mind with your current logic, what happens if: `len(p_routes[i])` is 2? you currently only check if it's less than two or greater than 2.

Comment: Thanks mate for pointing out the possible bug. But it was kept intentionally as the variable mentioned here would be a output from some ssh commands and as the way I did the regex filtering, the possible outcome could only be <2 or >2.

Answer (score 0):

With syntax errors, it is always wise to have a look at the preceding line to make sure it is also correct. As you missed the closing `)`, Python kept looking for it on the next line.

There are a number of areas you could make the code a bit cleaner. For example it is not necessary to keep using `range(len(x))` when you can just iterate over the list itself.

Hopefully you find the following ideas helpful:

```
for route in p_routes:
    length = len(route)

    if length > 2 :
        if route[2] == 'No Backup':   
            K += 1
            for z in range(length):
                nbup.write(K + 1, z, p_routes[i][z])

        elif route[0][0] == 'E':
            L += 1
            for z in range(length):
                ex.write(L, z, (p_routes[i][z]))

        elif route[0][0] == 'G':
            M += 1
            for z in range(length):
                gh.write(M ,z, p_routes[i][z])

    elif length == 2:
        print "It is equal to 2"
    else:
        print "It must be less than 2"
```

Note, `if x > 2` followed by an `else`, the else would imply the value is `<= 2`.

It is also possible to add one to a variable as follows: `L += 1`, this is shorthand for `L = L + 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion.. Yes the syntax error was coming from the non closing bracket indeed. I also figured out just after posting but was too bz doing the rest of the code completion. Now its working fine. :-)